Personal Safety Alarm pcb board (via Piezo Buzzer) Question - missing inductor part
I’m working on a personal project, and I could really use some help. I’m not an electrical engineer, so I apologize in advance if this is a basic question, but I’m a bit stuck.
I paid someone to design a personal alarm PCB board for me. It’s similar to those cheap $10 alarms you find on Amazon, but this one operates via a button instead of a pull pin. Everything seemed to be going well until I tried to order the PCB through PCBWay.
The issue I’m facing is that one of the items in the Bill of Materials (BOM) is missing a DigiKey Part Number, and PCBWay needs this to complete my order. The part that’s missing the Part Number is an inductor (L1), which is located close to the Piezo Buzzer on the board.
Unfortunately, the person I paid for the design has stopped responding, and I’m struggling to figure out what specific inductor I need. I’ve done my best to research and understand it on my own, but I’m feeling out of my depth here.
This project is important to me because I’m making this device for my grandma, and I want to get it right. I’ve attached images of the BOM, schematics, pick and place files, 3D render of the PCB board, and anything else that might be relevant. I also have the fabrication files (gerber/drill) that I can share if that is helpful too. I'm just not sure if it's possible to upload them here.
If anyone can help me identify the correct inductor or guide me on what to do next, I would greatly appreciate it!
Thank you so much in advance for your help!





Do you know the frequency of the sound generated by the processor?
The inductor is there to resonate with the capacitance of the piezo at the sound frequency. This will make the sound quite a bit louder. The value of the inductor satisfies freq=1/(2pisqrt(L*C))

@user69795 - I appreciate you replying. In full transparency, I have no idea what the frequency is. Is there a way for me to find that out so I can calculate the value of the inductor?
I asked the person who had this made for me for the piezo buzzer to hit 130 decibels if that is helpful?

Do you know that this thing actually works to specifications? The 'buzzer' is a raw element that resonates at 9kHz which is pretty useless as-is for the intended purpose. It should be mounted in a resonant cavity and that will determine the frequency. Do you have the firmware for the ATmega (presumably it's Arduino code.. )

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I am a finance analyst by trade, so most of this is out of my sphere of knowledge. I paid someone to have this done for me but unfortunately it seems like I did not get all that I paid for. I have nothing but the schematic for the PCB - no code that came along with it.
Any recommendation on where to start when it comes to figuring out what inductor to purchase?

@MauriceMaswary Frankly from this point, I would suggest cutting your losses and buying a quality commercial product.

Find an electronics hobbyist in your area to write the firmware. Put DNP in the row for the inductor of the Pick & Place file so PCBway omits that part. Test the circuit... you'll still hear the buzzer without the inductor...and experiment with different values for the inductor to maximize the sound. Since it's a through-hole part it's easy to do this with basic soldering ability that the hobbyist will have.
